# ios9 Image Download

Tags: ios, ios9

In iOS9, I can't download image form two domain.
Always only one domain's image can download.

The error message show that

```
error:Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=404
```

I already add this

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: It seems that one of the urls is invalid. 404 means that the image file was not found.

Comment: 404 means not found.  Are you sure an image exists at that URL.  Can you post the full URL?

Comment: a 404 is a resource not found error. Are you able to download the image by pasting the URL into Safari on your phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a little bit too less of information to give a definite answer. It does not seem to be an authentication or security issue.

However: 404 means, the URL (File) you are trying to reach cannot be found, are you sure the link/url is correct?

Comment: I think this issue from  SDWebImageManager, when i use  [self.picImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://testdomain/test.jpg"]];
 It's work.